# MySQL.. search using Fulltext or using Like? What is better?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

I'm working on a search feature for my application, I want to search all articles in the database. As of now, I'm using a `LIKE` in my queries, but I want to add a "Related Articles" feature, sort of like what SO has in the sidebar (which I see as a problem if I use Like).

What's better to use for MySQL searching, Fulltext or Like... or anything else I might not know about?

Also, I'm using the Kohana Framework, so If anybody knows an easy way to do fulltext matching using the query builder, I'd appreciate that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to consider that :

- [MySQL FULLTEXT indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) are only possibles for tables in [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) -- not for tables in [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb.html)

  - And only InnoDB supports foreign keys, transactions, ...
- Using `LIKE` is generally pretty slow and bad for performances, as it generally means doing a full-scan of the table for each search.

I would really not use any of those two solutions for any kind of big/real/important application...

Instead of those two possibilities, have you considered using a real fulltext indexing/search engine ?

For instance, you might want to take a look at :

- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) / [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)
- [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)

Note there is an implementation of Lucene that only requires PHP in Zend Framework : [`Zend_Search_Lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) -- might be useful if you cannot install any additionnal software on your server.